# MySQL Workbench reports “is not valid at this position for this server version” error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

For the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT( customers.name, '   ', customers.familyname ) As Name,
```

I  receive the following error message:

> "SELECT" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting: '(', WITH

I Have tried to run the query deleting the space between and other format but the SELECT error still remains.

could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Assuming that `SELECT` is in the middle of a query, you need to enclose it in parentheses `()`

Comment: I wonder where customers.name is coming from

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full complete query you want to execute, not just part of it. Also check that you don't have any queries before this query you haven't executed yet (with a terminating `;` or something like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query `SELECT CONCAT( customers.name, '   ', customers.familyname ) As Name` parses with no errors for me, but with the trailing comma it shows the mentioned error.